# How old is Mei Chang?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

How old is Mei Chang in *Full Metal Alchemist: Brotherhood*? Her age is never stated in the series.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Fandom Wiki](https://fma.fandom.com/wiki/Mei_Chang), Mei is 11-12 years old, being 14 by the end of the manga

[image: Mei Chang's bio from the Fandom Wiki]

Comment: any from-source citation to back this up?